# how to catch an index of an array that iterates (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to get an index inside an array each time it iterates, but i only get the length of that array. How can I do ?

I've made a  outside of other div in the HTML code, which each of them contains a photo with a little icon to open a modal, and so I want the image source of the modal outside change and get the value of that index (in the array with the small images) each time when I click on an image. Thank you very much for your help :)
Here is my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < zoom.length; i++)
{
    zoom[i].addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
        openModal();
    })
}

function openModal()
{
        j = i;
        image.src = './img/screenshotSite' + j + '.png';
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';

}
```

Comment: Firstly, I strongly recommend you use `let` & `const` to declare variables instead of `var`. Secondly, pass in the value of `i` which is the index in this case to the `openModal` function. And thirdly, please declare `j` as well, you are currently not declaring it and straight away initializing it. It may work, but it's bad coding practice.

Comment: 1. You are calling the function inside the loop so just change the () with a reference to that function preceded by return and 2) use `this` to refer to the specific html element being clicked. Also, when the openModel handler is called you are not accessing the **local** index inside the for loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to loop over an array. This ensures the correct value of the index when passed as argument to `openModal`:

```js
// I suppose this is an HTMLCollection, so need this to transform into an array
[...zoom]
  .forEach( (element, index) =>
    element.addEventListener('click', () => openModal(index) )
  );

function openModal(index)
{
  image.src = './img/screenshotSite' + index + '.png';
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I've learned with your help how to transform an array with some researches, then your method is much more simple to use, thank you very much. I succeed in renaming my photos because index begin at 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Just switch `for( var i=0 ....` with `for( let i=0 ....`
There is a difference between `let` and `var` regarding the `scope`.
More info in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).